# When does a $C^*$-algebra have no nonzero projection?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $\hat{A}$ its spectrum of $A$,the set of classes of non-zero irreducible representation of $A$ endowed with hull-kernel topology. suppose $\hat{A}$ is a non-compact connected Hausdorff space.

**Why**  $A$ cannot contain a nonzero projection?

Comment: That does not mean anythings: $A^*$ is a Banach space space so it is always connected, Hausdorff and non compact...  so there is no reason that $A$ cannot have a non zero projection.

Comment: $A^*$ or $\hat{A}$ is the spectrum of $A$

Comment: Dual space and spectrum are not the same things ! but ok now that you have edited the question makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Given $x\in A$ and $\alpha>0$ the set of $\pi\in \hat A$
such that $\|\pi(x)\|\geq \alpha$ is compact (Proposition 3.3.7 in Dixmier's ``C*-algebras"). Applied to a non-zero projection $p$, the set
of $\pi\in \hat A$ such that $\pi(p)\neq 0$ is compact (since then $\|\pi(p)\|=1$)
and non-empty. This set is also open (because $\pi\mapsto \|\pi(x)\| $ is l.s.c.; Proposition 3.3.2 in Dixmier's). In the question the spectrum is Hausdorff and connected. So we get a non-empty clopen set which must be the whole space. But the spectrum has also been assumed noncompact.